# How to retrieve passed data from another view controller? - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

**SendDataVc.m - Sending data from.**

**GetDataVC.m - Retrieving the data sent from SendDataVc.m**

**SendDataVC.m:**

```
NSString *theData = @"Sending data";

GetDataVC *passdataVC = [[GetDataVC alloc] init];

passdataVC.theData = theData;
```

**GetDataVC.h:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *theData;
```

**GetDataVC.m:**

```
-(void) getData
{
    NSLog( @"%@", _theData);
}
```

I tried doing this way but I got null instead.

Comment: That seems correct. Now the questions is where is called `getData`? Do you use Storyboard & Segue? How is presented `passdataVC`? Do you do a present? a Push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the application doesn't running to the function `- (void) getData`, you should call this function at `- (void)viewDidLoad` or `- (void)viewWillAppear` or something else like below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getData];
}
-(void)getData {
    NSLog(@"%@", _theData);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't instantiate a `UIViewController` that way.

Use the following approach, in which `@"GetDataVC"` is the identifier of the view controller you are going to instantiate:

```
GetDataVC *passdataVC = (GetDataVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GetDataVC"];
passdataVC.theData = theData;
```

Comment: Yes you can. You are assuming that the `GetDataVC` is in a Storyboard. But you can do all by code.

Comment: As stated in Apple document, `init` isn't a designated initializer for `UIViewController`. Actually, you can use `initWithNibName:bundle:` but not `init`.

Comment: I don't see an issue with that. `initWithNibName:bundle:` is usefull when using a Xib (with IBOutlets, etc.), but you should be able to do all programmatically.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Now, we have to wait for more detail from OP.

Answer (score -1):

Where you execute the function getData?
If you execute getData at viewDidLoad or init or somewhere before you set the data.
You can execute the function through a button.
I think that will deal the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just implement the setter of `theData` property.

Paste the code below to your `GetDataVC.m`.

```
- (void)setTheData:(NSString *)theData {
    _theData = theData;
    NSLog(@"theData has set: %@", _theData);
}
```

refrence: [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)